# Moving a Domain Away from Google Sites but Not Apps

Tags: web-development, google, gmail, google-sites

First, I looked for a question like this but couldn't find one.  There's a lot of people who want to move a domain to point at google sites - I actually want to move it away from google sites and point it at a hosted server.  I was able to figure out how to do this but then it broke my client's calendar and email.  I created matching email accounts on the new server but it doesn't fix his contact list and calendar stuff which use to be synced with google.

So my question is: can I move a domain away from google sites and point it at a hosted website without breaking the email and calendar? If the answer is no then we could always use two separate domains: one for email/calendar and one for website, but that doesn't seem like the perfect solution since really his email should be at the same domain as his website.  Will he just need to use a different address to sync his calendar and contacts?

I appreciate any help.  Thanks!

Comment: belongs on web masters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as you preserve the MX records and the CNAMEs to `ghs.google.com` they had you set up for the custom subdomains for mail/docs/calendar etc., you can point the www and no-www subdomains wherever you like.

Comment: I'll have to experiment with it to see if I can get the settings right, but I originally only changed the CName and was actually pretty sure I didn't change the MX records.  I'll take another look at it.

Comment: I'd guess you didn't break Google Calendar, just the URL they used to access it - i.e. http://calendar.example.com/ probably redirected to http://calendar.google.com/ when accessed. They'd still be able to access it directly via Google's URLs.

Comment: Thanks!  You were right about the URLs.  I had a feeling that was the direction to go but I wasn't sure the URLs should be changed to.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: You're most welcome. They let you set up others in the admin - docs.example.com, sites.example.com, etc. Worth peeking at it to make sure there aren't others you've missed.